# VBA code crashes consistently on 4 out of 47 almost identical sheets when copying. Why?

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I created a system of sheets for my employment office which organize volunteer information and schedules, and separates the schedules by month. When I want to add a new month, I have a macro that copies a "master" sheet for the month from the "master" workbook to all of the 47 different sheets. On four of these sheets, the below code crashes. On the remaining 43 it works just fine.

`sourceBook.Sheets(Array("February, "Events", "Volunteers")).Copy _
After:=destinationBook.Sheets("Volunteers")`

The code inside the with also crashes the same sheets, but not the others.

`With sourceBook.Sheets("February").UsedRange
     destinationBook.Sheets("February").Range("A1").Resize( _
            .Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Formula
End With`

On all sheets, the February sheet does not exist, and Events and Volunteers do. The code later deletes the duplicates. Why would Excel crash on only some of them (they seem to be identical at surface level) for this copy? If you need additional information, I'll supply it.

Comment: Would looping through a generated list of sheet names be a better option instead of addressing a sheet that does not exist and do you have any error trapping?

Comment: Is there something different about the sheet code names of the "problem" workbooks compared to the workbooks which show no errors?

Comment: The different workbooks all have names that come from a table of language names. I am a relatively new VBA user and don't know what sort of error trapping would be recommended.